# In Magento2 graphql i want to add a field to the root query of the Magento GraphQL API called `isLoggedIn`. This should return `Boolean`

Tags: magento2, graphql

In Magento2 graphql i want to add a field to the root query of the Magento GraphQL API called `isLoggedIn`. This should return `Boolean` whether the customer is logged in or not.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any GraphQL API Query named with "**isLoggedIn**" on Magento2 devdocs. Hence, I would not able to provide you the exact code to achieve your requirements.

However, I can explain you the concept vise. First, you need to create one file named as "**schema.graphqls**" in etc folder in your custom module (please create custom module if not exist any).

In this file, suppose if you want to add an additional field at root level of "**Cart Query**" then you need to write as below:

```
type Cart {
    extra_fields: YourExtraFields @resolver(class: "\\Namespace\\Modulename\\Model\\Resolver\\YourExtraFieldsResolver") @doc(description:"Additional custom fields used in the project.")
}

type YourExtraFields {
    field_first: Int! @doc(description: "The first field number count")
    field_second: Boolean! @doc(description: "The second field flag")
}
```

Now, you need to create a **resolver file** at the given path in model folder. In that file you just need to write your business logic and need to return all field values added in "**YourExtraFields**" schema.

Once the code is done, you can check in **Altair** and your new field(s) would be displayed in the respective api schema. I have done this on number of times in my project.

Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Happy to help!

Comment: Thanks for answer. Does it check whether the customer is logged in or not? Can you send me this small magento module having above mentioned functionality. I am new to magento graphql, so I have little beginner technical knowledge about it.

Comment: @SanaullahAhmad, if you are using any existing customer graphql api then you can access customer object  and you can check/use its properties. However, if you are building a new custom GraphQL api then you will to write whole business logic by your own. I will surely share some piece of demo code once I get some free time.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pratik explained how to do it, For further info do look into Magento [resolvers](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/develop/resolvers.html)

Which goes into your

```
type Cart {
    extra_fields: YourExtraFields @resolver(class: "\\Namespace\\Modulename\\Model\\Resolver\\YourExtraFieldsResolver") @doc(description:"Additional custom fields used in the project.")
}
```

Hope it helps.